# Accumulate sliding blocks into a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

In MATLAB, we can use `im2col` and `col2im` to transform from columns to blocks and back, for example

```
>> A = floor(30*rand(4,6))

A =

     8     5     2    13    15    11
    22    11    27    13    24    24
     5    18    23     9    23    15
    20    23    14    15    19    10

>> B = im2col(A,[2 2],'distinct')

B =

     8     5     2    23    15    23
    22    20    27    14    24    19
     5    18    13     9    11    15
    11    23    13    15    24    10

>> col2im(B,[2 2],[4,6],'distinct')

ans =

     8     5     2    13    15    11
    22    11    27    13    24    24
     5    18    23     9    23    15
    20    23    14    15    19    10
```

my question is that: after using `im2col` with sliding mode

```
>> B = im2col(A,[2 2],'sliding')

B =

     8    22     5     5    11    18     2    27    23    13    13     9    15    24    23
    22     5    20    11    18    23    27    23    14    13     9    15    24    23    19
     5    11    18     2    27    23    13    13     9    15    24    23    11    24    15
    11    18    23    27    23    14    13     9    15    24    23    19    24    15    10
```

I wish to get a *4*-by-*6* matrix *C* **from B(without knowing A)** that the value at each site equals the original value multiple the times of sampling.
In other word, `C(1,1)=A(1,1)`, `C(1,2)=A(1,2)*2`, `C(2,2) = A(2,2)*4`

Though we can easily implement with a `for`-loop, but the efficiency is critically low. So how to vectorize the implementation?

Comment: Can you show an example of what you would expect the output to be? Also the code you used to generate it with a for loop

Comment: Show your desired output. Show your code. Reshaping `B` into `A` is trivial. We need to know *exactly* what part you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you're desired output is

```
C = [  8    10     4    26    30    11
      44    44   108    52    96    48
      10    72    92    36    92    30
      20    46    28    30    38    10 ]
```

which I got by computing  `C = A.*S` where

```
S = [ 1     2     2     2     2     1
      2     4     4     4     4     2
      2     4     4     4     4     2
      1     2     2     2     2     1 ]_
```

The entries in `S` represent how many sliding blocks each entry is a member of.

**I believe your question boils down to how to construct the matrix `S`.**

### Solution:

```
S = min(min(1:M,M:-1:1),x)'*min(min(1:N,N:-1:1),y)
C = A.*S
```

where `A` is size `M`-by-`N`, and your sliding block is size `x`-by-`y`.

### Explanation:

In the given example, `M=4`, `N=6`, `x=2`, and `y=2`.
Notice the solution `S` can be written as the outer product of two vectors:

```
S = [1;2;2;1] * [1,2,2,2,2,1]
```

We construct each of these two vectors using the values of `M,N,x,y`:

```
min(1:M,M:-1:1)' == min(1:4,4:-1:1)'
                 == min([1,2,3,4], [4,3,2,1])'
                 == [1,2,2,1]'
                 == [1;2;2;1]
```

In this case, the extra `min(...,x)` does nothing since all entries are already `<=x`.

```
min(1:N,N:-1:1)  == min(1:6,6:-1:1)
                 == min([1,2,3,4,5,6],[6,5,4,3,2,1])
                 == [1,2,3,3,2,1]
```

This time the extra `min(...,y)` does matter.

```
min(min(1:N,N:-1:1),y) == min([1,2,3,3,2,1],y)
                       == min([1,2,3,3,2,1],2)
                       == [1,2,2,2,2,1]
```

Comment: usefull answer, but actually I mean to get C from B without knowing A